# Onchange function don't work in wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I try to display some information (Adresse) from My database in a WordPress page using a drop-down list, but when I select an item (Nom) from the drop-down list it displays nothing.
 I did follow the right answer here: [ajax call to populate form fields from database query when select value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957823/ajax-call-to-populate-form-fields-from-database-query-when-select-value-changes)
So i don't know wht error i made here :

The dropdown list code:

```
<select class='Nom' onchange="showUser(this.value)" name='Nom' id='Nom'>
<option value="">--- Select ---</option>

    [insert_php]
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "somapam_bd");

     $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Nom FROM herboristes");

    while($ligne_liste=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$ligne_liste['Nom'].'">'.$ligne_liste['Nom']."</option>\n";
    }
    echo '</select>';
    [/insert_php]
    <div id="txtHint" type="text" name="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

the onchange function i insert it in the index.php :

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").value="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

      document.getElementById("txtHint").value = this.responseText;

    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","formdata.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The formdata.php code:

```
 <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "somapam_bd");



  $q = intval($_GET['q']);


 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM herboristes where Nom = '".$q."'");


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $cID = $row['Adresse'];

}
echo $cID ;


   ?>
```

Comment: Maybe the path should be "/formdata.php".

Comment: Since it's WordPress, Why you are not using jQuery ??

Comment: @Roamer-1888 it still the same problem and the same error

Comment: @FAROUKBLALOU I did try it with jQuery but it didn't work too, this is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807930/add-onchange-function-to-the-chosen-jquery-wordpress

Comment: If you get 404, then it has to be the URL that's wrong. Have you saved "formdata.php" to the right place? Have you tried a fully qualified URL, starting with "http://" or "https://"?

Comment: @MohamedRedaAguezzoul Try to debug it like this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes i think it's the right place (the same place of  the file index.php

Comment: Sounds right. All I can think is that the server is somehow set up to block GET requests (which would be very unusual but not impossible). Try POST.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the same problem I this the problem in the data place

Comment: Try typing the full URL "http://...." into your browser's address bar. If it's correct, you should see the JSON.

Comment: It's work when i chnge the place but i got another error :

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange ((index):332)

Comment: I am trying to fix it

Comment: I fixed all the problems and i don't get any result when i chose an item from the dropdown list :/

Comment: That's some serious strange code... Instead of using that `[insert_php]` shortcode, build your own shortcode that will much more effective/easier. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43822001/1287812), [this](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9546/201) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812)

Comment: @brasofilo it's a php plugin i used to insert php code to a specific pge in wordpress.. i used it to build the dropdown list and it work :)